# Interpretation of a residual scatter plot

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals

[image]

Hi all, I need to make a basic statement about whether this residual scatterplot looks normal, homoscedastic and linear. I understand that there are probably too few data points to make any conclusive statements but I do have to make a general statement before I move onto more detailed analyses and I honestly have no clue. Could you please help me with the interpretation?

The research question is looking at whether annual sales performance can be predicted from extraversion, gender, years employed and cognitive ability.If there are any problems I do not need to resolve them. I just need to make a statement about them and move on.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2):

[I am un-deleting this initially rushed post to save the comments, which map directly to an online post outside CV, and to finish what I started.]

---

In a very useful post within the [Statwing website](https://www.statwing.com) the "ideal" [residual plot](http://docs.statwing.com/interpreting-residual-plots-to-improve-your-regression/#hetero-header) fulfills the following criteria:

> 1. They [*the data points*] are pretty symmetrically distributed, tending to cluster towards the middle of the plot.
> 2. They’re clustered around the lower single digits of the y-axis (e.g., 0.5 or 1.5, not 30 or 150).
> 3. In general there aren’t clear patterns.

I believe that these points are not presented in the linked page as indicative of any particular breach in the [Gauss-Markov assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem), either homoscedasticity or uncorrelated errors, rather they seem to be more of a heuristic listing to quickly assess any obvious problems. However, the comments below are, naturally, enlightening.

With regards to the specific questions in the OP,

1. **Normality**: In the absence of a QQ plot, the symmetry in the scatter of data points above and below the zero line is consistent with a normal distribution of the errors with $\mathbb E(\varepsilon)=0$. Mentally turning the plot on its side and "allowing" the points to drop by gravity gives the impression of a normal histogram in the making.
2. **homoscedasticity**: The spread on either side of the baseline is consistent across the predicted values. It is expected to see some more extreme values at some points, particularly in areas that happen to be dense. This would be an example of heteroskedasticity:

[image]

3. **Linear**: There is no polynomial oscillating pattern in the residuals as we progress along the $x$-axis, for example an arching parabolic shape, such as in this example:

[image]

Comment: I think your reading of this particular plot is correct.  However, (1) Departure from symmetry helps detect local trends but not heteroscedasticity.  (2) is not a relevant criterion.  It is possible for heteroscedasticity to take almost any shape: the residual plots can fill triangles pointed left, pointed right, X shapes, and worse.  (3) "No clear patterns" is a little too vague to be of real use--people need training before they can understand what is a relevant "pattern" and what is not.